# Why is \left( discouraged?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

From George Grätzer's Book; *More Math Into LaTeX* (5th edition) at the subsection ***2.6 Your errors: Davey's Dos and Don'ts***, it is mentioned that when you submit an article to a journal,

5. Don't use **\left\{**,  **\right\}**, **\left(**, **\right)**, and so on, [...]. Even when **\left** and **\right** do not change the size of the symbol, they add extra space after the closing delimiter.

Why shouldn't we use these very useful commands?

Is there an alternative, except manually change the size?

Comment: ...isn't the answer within your question? :...they add extra space after the closing delimiter."

Comment: The `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command of `mathtools` is a good alternative that does not introduce extra space.